# Custom print dialog in VB6

Tags: printing, vb6, printdialog

How do I create this custom print dialog and get the values of the red options when the user clicks ok?

The print dialog below is not created manually, the app I took this screenshot from is probably modifying the default print dialog.

The items circled in red is associated with some data found in the app I took the screenshot from.

The class name of this dialog is **#32770 (Dialog)** which is the same print dialog found in notepad, wordpad, and vb6 common dialog print. So it is clear that it is modifying the dialog, adding controls to it somehow

[image: custom print dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at [Customizing Common Dialog Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but don't expect this to be simple from VB6.  it is clumsy enough in C++.

You could just create your own dialog Form.

*Update:*

Perhaps consider using the download in [HOW TO: Raise and Control Print Dialog Boxes from Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322710)?

Comment: if in case i consider creating my own dialog, how do i get these features as collate, copies, print to file, printer properties etc.

Comment: thanks for the info, but this is changing the print dialog properties only, not add custom controls etc